From where does Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable pick its value in nunit and referenced blazor web assembly
I was actually trying this code section in NUnit .
using NUnit.Framework;


namespace BlazorClientApp.Tests
{
    public class CounterTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void CounterComponent_ShouldHaveInitialCountZero()
        {
            var envVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
            Assert.AreEqual("MyCheck", envVariable);
        }
    }
}

I have already referenced this nunit project with my blazor wasm project.
Here i was expecting that it will give me wasm environment variable but it's returning null what could be the reason.

This is an independent NUnit testing project, direct access to the environment variables of the project being tested is not possible.
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
This command directly accesses operating system-level environment variables, not the environment variables within the Blazor WebAssembly project.
Ways to get the value of "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT":
In Blazor projects, configurations and environment variables are typically accessed using the IConfiguration interface, which is not accessible in test projects.
Therefore, in test projects, you can use ConfigurationBuilder and MemoryConfigurationSource to create a simulated configuration environment, enabling tests to access the required environment variable values.
Steps:
1.You should first ensure that the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable is correctly configured in your Blazor project.
2.Create a service to retrieve this value：
namespace BlazorAssm.Services
{
    public class ConfigurationService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ConfigurationService(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public string GetEnvironmentVariable()
        {
            return _configuration["ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"];
        }
    }
}

3.Use ConfigurationBuilder and MemoryConfigurationSource to create a simulated configuration environment in the Test project:
using BlazorAssm.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NUnitTest
{
    public class Tests
    {
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            var inMemorySettings = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                {"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "MyCheck"}
            };

            IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddInMemoryCollection(inMemorySettings)
                .Build();

            _configurationService = new ConfigurationService(configuration);

        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            // Act
            var Result = _configurationService.GetEnvironmentVariable();

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual("MyCheck", Result);
        }
    }
}


I feel like here in the nuit you are explicitly adding the environment variable inside the nunit process rather than fetching it from the Blazor app's launch setting ?

Yes, this value is automatically set during application runtime based on the execution environment. Therefore, when running test projects, since the application isn't built, the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable remains unset. Hence, it's necessary to simulate the build configuration, and therefore, it must be manually set in the test project. You can use the set value to test different scenarios in various environments.

Could you tell me the purpose of retrieving the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable? May there be another way to achieve it. Or you can try to fetch the variable directly by reading the "launchSettings.json" file.

Actually I am trying to access appsettings.json from the blazor application into the nunit project using playwright. I could hardcode it but actually based on the environment the blazor application is running i want to pick that up in the nuinit project somewhat like this :

using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration; 
namespace MyProj; 
internal class ConfigHelper 
{ 
public static readonly IConfiguration configuration; 
static ConfigHelper()<br/>
{<br/>
    string env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")<br/>
    configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddUserSecrets<ConfigHelper>()
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();<br/>
}<br/>

}

I was expecting that it would pickup dynamically rather it was returning null.
